# Flutter Video Player appears on second time webpage loads and overlay buttons not functional

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

Link: [Website](https://63ebe850a9435500070baaec--elaborate-fudge-f549c7.netlify.app/#/)

Problem: The video on the front page below the video banner does not render until you navigate away from the page and return back. When the video finally appears and plays, the play button does not work. Is there a way to have the video appear on first appearance and have the overlay work as expected.

I am using the latest `video_player` widget to play the video. Other videos I have implemented work just fine.

When I debug my flutter web application, the application pauses at `videoController.play()` inside `initState()`. I continue execution to see if there is was an exception, but nothing new shows in debug console.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found to work is by setting the volume to 0 then starting the video.

This allows the video to play, but the overlay still not functioning as expected, so I just removed it. For now it works, but still wondering on how the overlay can be implemented.